# image naming convention for ipad mini

Tags: ios, image, background, naming-conventions

I have a question about image naming conventions in universal apps, especially for ipad mini.

I am developing a universal App across iphone 4s, ipad 3 (i.e., ipad with retina), and ipad mini.  I have an image that I want to load as a background in the app.  I am using

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"background"]
```

to get the image.  This works for iphone and ipad, but not for ipad mini.

To debug, I used

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"background" ofType:@"png"];
NSLog(@"background image: %@",filePath);
```

to make sure that the right image was being chosen.  On ipad I get

```
background image: /var/mobile/Applications/[...RESOURCEPATH...]/background.png
```

and on iphone I get

```
background image: /var/mobile/Applications/[...RESOURCEPATH...]/background~iphone.png
```

but on ipad mini I get

```
background image: (null)
```

The truly strange part is that, I had included named versions of the image:

```
background~iphone.png
background@2x~iphone
background-Portrait~ipad
background-Portrait@2x~ipad
```

but NOT background.png by itself.

When I realized this mistake, I added the background.png image, and now my background shows up on the mini, too.

What is going on here, and what is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only place you'll see "modifiers" (like "`-PortraitUpsideDown`") in image names will be the launch images, as described in [this Apple documentation (look in the "Providing Launch Images for Different Orientations" section)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW11).

You really should simply have just two Background images.  One for regular resolution and one for Retina resolution (i.e. the "`@2x`" suffix).  These two images should be able to handle being rotated nicely.

Comment: @Dautermann: Ok, I can follow that convention... but this doesn't explain why the iPad found the image but the mini did not.  Also, the iPad found an image name that did not exist?

Comment: The file should be named "`background@2x.png`" for it to be picked up on your Retina display iPad Mini.  Filenames with the suffixes "`@2x~ipad.png`" and "`@2x~iphone.png`" aren't valid, or at least they aren't officially documented anywhere.  I wouldn't name my image files that.

Comment: Is the mini a retina display?  I thought the iPad 3 is, but the mini is like an iPad 2?

Comment: You're right. [The current mini is *not* a retina display](http://store.apple.com/us/question/answers/ipad/does-the-ipad-mini-have-retina-display/QDDHUFUAUA2DHKUDC), so in this case your "`background.png`" (normal resolution) file is what should be found and loaded.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann: the ~iphone suffix is documented here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/ImageSoundResources/ImageSoundResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH7-SW17

Comment: The link in the answer is dead. Is there an authoritative source to what suffixes exist, and which ones are required in the file name vs there only to disambiguate otherwise identical file names, and so on?